# get article id by axios with vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Trying to reach article's id and fetch it. But in somewhere I do some mistakes. Because vuex returns empty object and router-link is fails.

so far, I made some something like below.

```
state: {
    article: {},
},

getters: {
    bringArticle(state){
        return state.article;
    }
},

mutations: {
    updateArticle(state, article){
        state.article = article;
    }
},

actions: {
    getArticle(context, id){
        axios.get("/api/articles/" + id)
        .then((response) => {
            context.commit("updateArticle", response.data);
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
}
```

Clearly this `axios.get("/api/articles/" + id)` is not working out...

by the way. I see id's data at the endpoint without a problem. Just stuck the axios part. How can I reach the id?

```
Route::get("/articles/{id}", "Api\ArticlesController@singleArticle");
```

Comment: are you calling `dispatch('getArticle')` to get the article? it should be something like `this.$store.dispatch('getArticle', 1);` from within a component, with `1` being the id you want to load.

Comment: You can either change your action to be `getArticle(context, { id })` or change the way you call dispatch to `this.$store.dispatch('getArticle', this.$route.params.id)`. The way you have now, your action expects a number, and is passed an object.

Comment: thank you for the comments. I figured it out and post the asnwer. @Leite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, it took some time to figure it out. And not sure it is the best way,  but it's working now.

I set the route-link like below to go to ID.

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'detail', params: { id: article.id} }">
```

then I created `api.js` file and export my calls.

```
var apiUrl = "api/articles/";

export default {

    getArticles: function(){
        return axios.get(apiUrl);
    },

    getArticle: function( id ){
        return axios.get(apiUrl + id);
    },

}
```

inside my `store.js` I changed my action commit like:

```
getArticle( { commit }, data ){
    path.getArticle( data.id )
    .then( function( response ){
        commit( 'setArticle', response.data );
    })
    .catch( function(){
        console.log(error)
    });
},
```

Last, I dispatch it `Detail.vue`

```
created(){
    this.$store.dispatch( 'getArticle', {
        id: this.$route.params.id
    });
},
```